# What are the impacts of (dlopen failed: undefined symbol: memdup) with respect to SNMP?

Tags: shared-libraries, snmp

While working on SNMP, I am not able to execute `snmpwalk` or `snmpset`. Then I checked `snmpd -H`.

I see an error as:

> dlopen(/lib/libvcpeLiTapMediationTable.so) failed: /lib/libvcpeLiTapMediationTable.so: undefined symbol: memdup
>   dlopen(/lib/libvcpeLiTapStreamTable.so) failed: /lib/libvcpeLiTapStreamTable.so: undefined symbol: memdup

I think that my library might not be opening dynamically due to this.

When I load my packages in CentOS as rpms, I have no errors.
But for the same code, when I load my packages in Ubuntu as debian packages, I see this error.

Queries:

1. Is there any problem with SNMP installation (since it works on CentOS but not on Ubuntu)? Or is something missing in my debian packages?
2. Please explain the impact of this error on my operations.

Any relevant answers will be helpful as I am new to this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `libvcpeLiTapMediationTable.so` depends on function `memdup()`. This is defined on your CentOS and wherever it was built, in either Net-SNMP or one of the libraries it or `libvcpeLiTapMediationTable.so` links to at run time, but is not defined on your Ubuntu. Consequently, it can't be loaded at won't work.

Net-SNMP defined `memdup()` in `snmplib/tools.c`, but this was renamed to `netsnmp_memdup()` to avoid conflicts with other libraries that might define their own version according to [change history](https://sourceforge.net/p/net-snmp/code/ci/9a6f566392a3cf12dab488a76d69fc873dbec2ac/). Perhaps you are using two different versions of Net-SNMP between your two distros, one with and one without that change.

Comment: Yes, the information was helpful. What is the impact of such errors? Won't any snmp operations on these tables work at all?

Comment: I would imagine not. I am only guessing here based on the file name, but I imagine that file is implementing a [probably proprietary, since I can't find anything about it] table as a sub-agent that is loaded dynamically at run time into your main agent to provide its functionality. Since it can't be loaded due to this error, whatever it implements won't be added to the main agent.

Comment: Why don't we get this type of error at compile time since it is 'undefined symbol' error?

Comment: Because it probably *was* defined at compile time. But wherever it was defined at compile time, it's not there in your Ubuntu. Try running `ldd` on your `.so` file to find out what it links to, and then `readelf -s <file> | grep memdup` on each of those on each of your build/run hosts to find out where it is/isn't defined.

Comment: Can you please confirm what does the netsnmp_memdup return? 
 void *netsnmp_memdup(const void * from, size_t size); Does this return the duplicated memory block? 

As the function int  memdup(u_char ** to, const void * from, size_t size); used to return the value of type int. Is the duplicated memory block assigned to the argument "u_char ** to" here?

Comment: Yes, it looks like the function signature changed from returning int success/fail status to returning the pointer to the allocated memory. https://sourceforge.net/p/net-snmp/code/ci/9a6f566392a3cf12dab488a76d69fc873dbec2ac/tree/snmplib/tools.c?diff=b2725964bde921b6285e3a59a512552cae0a0ca5